# Screen resolution Issues, Intel HD graphics, Samsung Syncmaster SA10

Tags: xorg, display, intel-graphics, display-resolution, xrandr

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS for the first time on my computer, but quickly came across a problem. My resolution settings were limited to 800x600 and 1024x768. After following instructions from across the net, I have used xrandr to get the resolution to 1368x786 (for some reason, this is what `cvt 1366 786` output gets me to). The problem now is, the screen is not centered, neither does it seem to be the write aspect ratio (there is vertical overscan but horizontally the are unused pixels).

I am using Intel HD graphics and the monitor is a Syncmaster SA10 (1366x786)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replaced the cable.
Faulty VGA cable; there was a pin missing on the one end.

The screen displays perfectly now.